# make csv data import case insensitive

Tags: r, csv, import, case-sensitive

I realize this is a total newbie one (as always in my case), but I'm trying to learn R, and I need to import hundreds of csv files, that have the same structure, but in some the column names are uppercase, and in some they are lower case.

so I have (for now)

```
flow0300csv  <- Sys.glob("./csvfiles/*0300*.csv")

for (fileName in flow0300csv) {     
   flow0300 <- read.csv(fileName, header=T,sep=";",
   colClasses = "character")[,c('CODE','CLASS','NAME')] 
}
```

but I get an error because of the lower cases. I have tried to apply "tolower" but I can't make it work. Any tips?

Comment: `colnames(flow0300) <- tolower(colnames(flow0300))`

Comment: I am confused. If you are making all of the column names lower case, why does the sample code have upper case column names?

Comment: Read the first row (header) of one file, check the positions of the columns of interest, then create a character vector of the same length as number of columns in your data. This vector should be `"NULL"` in all positions of columns you dont want to read and `"character"` in the positions of columns of interest. Use this vector for the `colClasses = ` argument to read only the correct columns. Then, convert column names to make them equal or rbind to a single data set

Answer (score 1):

After reading the .csv-file you may want to convert the column names to all uppercase with

```
flow0300 <- read.csv(fileName, header = T, sep = ";", colClasses = "character")
colnames(flow0300) <- toupper(colnames(flow0300))
flow0300 <- flow0300[, c("CODE", "CLASS", "NAME")]
```

**EDIT:** Extended solution with the input of @xraynaud.

Comment: The problem it, is won't read the csv file if the columns are lower case so I get an error message: "Error in `[.data.frame`(read.csv(fileName, header = T, sep = ";", colClasses = "character"), : undefined columns selected" 
 I guess I can import the whole thing without specifiying the columns I want (total nr of columns around 50) but it would have been nicer to just pick the three cols I'm interested in and output them to a new csv file...

Comment: It's not that it won't read the dataframe if the headers are lowercase but that you only keep the uppercase columns columns once you've read it: `read.table()` reads all the dataframe but  `[,c('CODE','CLASS','NAME')]` only keep these three columns. You have to first read the dataframe `flow0300 <- read.csv(fileName, header=T,sep=";",
   colClasses = "character")`; then convert colnames to lower (or upper) case `colnames(flow0300) = tolower(colnames(flow0300))` and then keep only the columns you want `flow0300 = flow0300[,c('code','class','name')] `

Answer (score 1):

The problem here isn't in reading the CSV files, it's in trying to index using column names that don't actually exist in your "lowercase" data frames.

You can instead use `grep()` with `ignore.case = TRUE` to index to the columns you want.

```
tmp <- read.csv(fileName, header = T, sep = ";",
                colClasses = "character")
ind <- grep(patt = "code|class|name", x = colnames(tmp), 
            ignore.case = TRUE)
tmp[, ind]
```

You may want to look into `readr::read_csv2()` or even `data.table::fread()` for better performance.