# Import CSV with case-invariant na.strings argument

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file I am trying to import with inconsistent case variants to indicate missing data, such as:

```
read.csv(
  text = "A,B,C
  1,Not indicated, NOT indicated
  4,abc,not indicated
  NOT INDICATED, def, noT InDiCated")

#                 A             B              C
# 1               1 Not indicated  NOT indicated
# 2               4           abc  not indicated
# 3   NOT INDICATED           def  noT InDiCated
```

I am trying to import them as `NA` *within* the `read.csv()` function (or analogous function from another package), ignoring the case. My desired output would be:

```
#      A    B    C
# 1    1   NA   NA
# 2    4  abc   NA
# 3   NA  def   NA
```

The `read.csv()` command's `na.string` accepts a character vector of strings to replace with `NA`, but the case variants are initially unknown and there are too many permutations for this to be practical.

Is there a way to use regex or another alternative to import all the case variations as `NA` without specifying each one of them? In this specific case, it is important to achieve this *while reading in the data* (ie, within `read.csv` or similar) and not in additional steps (ie, read in data, then use additional code to clean, (ie, as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69900655/replace-whole-value-by-na-if-specific-character-is-found)).

I've tried:

```
read.csv(
  text = "A,B,C
  1,Not indicated, NOT indicated
  4,abc,not indicated
  NOT INDICATED, def, noT InDiCated" 
  na.strings = "(?i)not (?i)indicated") ## nothing is replaced

read.csv(
  text = "A,B,C
  1,Not indicated, NOT indicated
  4,abc,not indicated
  NOT INDICATED, def, noT InDiCated", 
  na.strings = c("not indicated"), 
  ignore.case = TRUE) # Returns error/unused argument

read.csv(
  text = "A,B,C
  1,Not indicated, NOT indicated
  4,abc,not indicated
  NOT INDICATED, def, noT InDiCated",
  na.strings = stringr::regex("not indicated", ignore_case = TRUE)) # does not return NA for any of the variants
```

I've tried analogous approaches with `data.table::fread` and `readr::read_csv`, but none of them return the desired output (returns output/errors similar to above). Unfortunately none of the existing SO questions address the specific concern (ie, [make csv data import case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069423/make-csv-data-import-case-insensitive) or [Case-insensitive search of a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671719/case-insensitive-search-of-a-list-in-r))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace within fread - using `sed`:

```r
data.table::fread("sed 's/not indicated/NA/gI' tmp.csv")
#     A  B  C
# 1:  1 NA NA
# 2:  4  5 NA
# 3: NA  8 NA
```

---

Check OS then run equivalent of "sed" command:

- [Determine if a script is running in Windows or Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096473/determine-if-a-script-is-running-in-windows-or-linux)

Comment: This is great! But I guess not portable to windows?

Comment: @Axeman true, then you have to find powershell alternative for sed. There could be a simple check before freading, find out the OS, then run relevant command.

Comment: @zx8754, out of interest, I would like to ask how such a check would look like. Based on `.Platform$OS.type`?

Comment: @Friede yes, this is what I had in mind, there are many ways, edited, see the linked post.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading comment to an answer after clarification:

You could import the raw text, apply a regex replacement, and then pass it to `read.csv`. That will hold off the guessing of the column types etc until after certain strings are stripped out.

It's not exactly what you want, but I don't think that's possible with the way `scan()` is called for `na.strings=`.

A (not very robust) attempt which could be a starting point:

```
read.csv(
   text=gsub("not indicated", "NA", 
          readChar("test.csv", nchars=file.size("test.csv"), useBytes=TRUE),
          ignore.case=TRUE), 
   na.strings="NA", strip.white=TRUE
)

##   A  B  C
##1  1 NA NA
##2  4  5 NA
##3 NA  8 NA
```